# I can't access my sql server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server but I get this error

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to BRIAN.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

This is my connectionstring so far

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ImagesSample-20140730183036;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ImagesSample-2014073018303‌​6.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Have you just set up your SQL Server? You could try using `localhost` or `local` as a server name if you run it from the same machine.

Comment: @Alex the way the OP is describing it I suspected an external "server" but it is very unclear. We could do with some clarification of whether this is an external server or a local installation.

Comment: Please show us your **connection string** that you're using!

Comment: Open `services.msc` on the server that hosts the instance and ensure that `SQL Server (MSSQLServer)` has started.

Comment: This is my connectionstring so far

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ImagesSample-20140730183036;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ImagesSample-20140730183036.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1):

This is because wherever your application is cannot connect to the SQL server. This could be down to a whole manner of causes. Here are a few of the most common:

- Is the machine hosting the SQL database actually switched on and running?
- Are the appropriate SQL services running?
- Try to connect to the SQL instance from the SQL machine itself?
- Try to connect to the database server from your application server (dev box) using a different application - Management Studio or LinqPad perhaps?
- Is your connection string right?
- Is there a firewall protecting the SQL box?
- Is there a firewall preventing outbound communication? Turn off firewalls and eliminate one by one
- Is your connection string referring to the server by IP? DNS name? Is the DNS correct? You can usually check this by trying to connect to the server using the same details using a ping/nslookup/rdp

It's unlikely this sort of exception is caused by invalid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Do all you SQL server communication using TCP/IP. The default port of SQL Server installation is 1433. This port can be changed through SQL Server Configuration Manager. TCP/IP should be enabled for SQL Server to be connected.

Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> Select TCP/IP